# How can I build a Docker image in a custom directory instead of the default directory?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm new to Docker. Say if I want to build a Docker image called proj-xxx-img and I want the built image to be placed inside a folder called test (/opt/test/). Is it possible to do so ?

The command I am running at the moment is :
docker build -t proj-xxx-img .

How can I build it inside /opt/test/ directory ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm understood correctly, you want to see an "image file" of your Docker image somewhere in your machine, right? If so, may I know what the purpose of having an image file is?

Comment: The built image doesn't exist outside of Docker's internal filesystem space; you can't have it built in another directory, and you can't usefully see the files that correspond to the image.

Comment: David Maze comment is perfect. If you want, there are other useful commands to inspect what happens behind the scenes: `docker image inspect` and `docker container inspect` will give you many useful details